# Why the form is not performing validation?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a following form.
it accepts the data, makes entry in database correctly.
but it also accepts blank inputs.
i have done following code to perform validations but its not working.

```
<form novalidate="" name="storeForm" action="book.php" onsubmit="book.php"
    method="POST">
    <div class="storeInputContainer">
        <input class="storeInput" placeholder="Name *" name="Name" type="text"
            required>
    </div>
    <div class="storeInputContainer">
        <input class="storeInput" placeholder="Phone Number *" name="Number"
            type="phone" required>
    </div>
    <div class="lineBreak">
        <br>
    </div>
    <div class="storeInputContainer">
        <input class="storeInput" placeholder="Address *" name="Address"
            type="text" required>
    </div>
    <div class="storeInputContainer">
        <select name="Postcode" value="" placeholder="Post Code/Area"
            class="storeInput" required onchange="myNewfunction(this);">

            <option value="411002">411002 (Pune City H.O.)</option>
            <option value="411004">411004 (Deccan Gymkhana)</option>
            <option value="411005">411005 (Shivajinagar H.O.)</option>
            <option value="411006">411006 (Yerawada)</option>
            <option value="411007">411007 (Ganeshkhind)</option>
            <option value="411008">411008 (N.C.L.)</option>
            <option value="411009">411009 (Parvati)</option>
            <option value="411010">411010 (S.S.C. Board)</option>
            <option value="411011">411011 (Kasba Peth)</option>
            <option value="411012">411012 (Dapodi)</option>
            <option value="411013">411013 (Hadapsar)</option>
            <option value="411014">411014 (Dunkirk Line)</option>
            <option value="411015">411015 (Dighi Camp)</option>
            <option value="411016">411016 (Model Colony)</option>
            <option value="411017">411017 (Pimpri Colony)</option>
            <option value="411018">411018 (Pimpri Penicillin Factory)</option>
            <option value="411019">411019 (Chinchwad East)</option>
            <option value="411020">411020 (Khadaki/Range Hill)</option>
            <option value="411021">411021 (Armament )</option>
            <option value="411022">411022 (S.R.P.F.)</option>
            <option value="411023">411023 (N.D.A.)</option>
            <option value="411024">411024 (Khadakwasala)</option>
            <option value="411025">411025 (I.A.T. Pune)</option>
            <option value="411026">411026 (Bhosari Indus.estate)</option>
            <option value="411027">411027 (Aundh Camp)</option>
            <option value="411028">411028 (Hadapsar_)</option>
            <option value="411030">411030 (S.P. College)</option>
            <option value="411031">411031 (C.M.E.)</option>
            <option value="411032">411032 (I.A.F. station)</option>
            <option value="411033">411033 (Chinchwad Gaon)</option>
            <option value="411034">411034 (Kasarwadi)</option>
            <option value="411035">411035 (Akurdi)</option>
            <option value="411036">411036 (Mundhwa)</option>
            <option value="411037">411037 (Market Yard)</option>
            <option value="411038">411038 (Kothrud/Ex. Service man colony)</option>
            <option value="411039">411039 (Bhosari Gaon)</option>
            <option value="411040">411040 (Wanawadi)</option>
            <option value="411041">411041 (Wadgaon Budruk)</option>
            <option value="411042">411042 (Swargate)</option>
            <option value="411043">411043 (Dhankawadi)</option>
            <option value="411044">411044 (Pimpri Chinchwad)</option>
            <option value="411045">411045 (Pashan)</option>
            <option value="411046">411046 (Katraj)</option>
            <option value="411047">411047 (Lohgaon)</option>
            <option value="411048">411048 (N.I.B.M.)</option>
            <option value="411051">411051 (Anandnagar)</option>
            <option value="411052">411052 (Navasahyadri/Warje Malwadi)</option>
            <option value="411053">411053 (Shivaji Hsg Society)</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="extraLarge"></div>
    <div class="callBack">
        <button type="submit" class="callBackBtn"> Call me Back</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

please Help me regarding this.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Just adding a required tag isn't enough, not all webbrowser support it. You should check it on the serverside aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML5 'require' tags are not enough validation on their own.  Not all browsers support them, older browsers will ignore them.  You still need to process your form submission using PHP before writing any form data to the database.

Also `novalidate=""` and `onsubmit="book.php"` will not do what you think they will.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put Js file for validating your form. You require client side validation with HTML5.